# How to calculate the required heap size for dynamic memory allocation in a kernel?

Tags: cuda

I am facing the problem that if I set the CUDA heap size to the total amount of memory I need to allocate in a kernel, the heap is still not big enough to serve all allocations.

This is a minimal example which represents my use case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NARR 8

__global__
void heaptest(int N){
    double* arr[NARR];

    __shared__ double* arrS[NARR];

    if(threadIdx.x == 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < NARR; i++){
            arrS[i] = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * N);

            if(arrS[i] == NULL)
                printf("block %d, array %d is NULL\n", blockIdx.x, i);
        }            
    }

    __syncthreads();

    for(int i = 0; i < NARR; i++){
        arr[i] = arrS[i];
    }
}

size_t getHeapSizePerBlock(int N){
    return sizeof(double) * N * NARR;
}

int main(){

    int N = 4000 * 18;

    int nBlocks = 1;

    size_t myheapsize = getHeapSizePerBlock(N) * nBlocks;

    printf("set heap size to %lu\n", myheapsize);
    cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, myheapsize);

    size_t a;

    cudaDeviceGetLimit(&a, cudaLimitMallocHeapSize);
    printf("heap size is now %lu\n", a);

    heaptest<<<nBlocks, 128>>>(N);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with nvcc V8.0.61.

nvcc -arch=sm_60 heaptest.cu -o heaptest

Program output is

```
set heap size to 4608000
heap size is now 4653056
block 0, array 7 is NULL
```

So, even if the heap size is larger than the required size, it is not large enough.
How do I correctly calculate the required size in this case?

Comment: Can you try it with a pow 2 size `N = 4096*32`

Comment: @dari I tried with N = n * 32 for n in [1, 4096]. It worked for n < 1665, and n = 2497. For n = 1664 the output is "set heap size to 3407872
heap size is now 4194304", for n = 2497 it is "set heap size to 5113856
heap size is now 5177344"

Comment: what GPU are you running on?

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to compute the *exact* size required by your application's heap, since you don't have control over CUDA's memory manager. Just like when allocating CPU memory where you have the OS' memory manager, CUDA has it's own memory manager. When you allocate multiple arrays in the heap, you have no guarantee that they will fit perfectly in the size of the heap, there may exist some overhead.

To exemplify, I did a small modification to your code to print also the memory address returned by malloc:

```
printf("block %d, array %d is %p\n", blockIdx.x, i, arrS[i]);
```

Here's what I get on my GTX 1070:

```
block 0, array 0 is 0x102059a8d20
block 0, array 1 is 0x10205600120
block 0, array 2 is 0x1020568f280
block 0, array 3 is 0x10205738520
block 0, array 4 is 0x102057c7680
block 0, array 5 is 0x10205870920
block 0, array 6 is 0x102058ffa80
block 0, array 7 is (nil)
```

First thing to note is that memory locations are not (always) contiguous/increasing (e.g., array 0 > array 6 > ... > array 1), but that's not too important for us. Also, if you subtract the memory addresses in decreasing order, you will not get the size you passed to `malloc()`, which in your case was always `sizeof(double) * N`, or `576000` bytes. For example:

> 0x1020568f280 - 0x10205600120 = 586080 bytes (array 1)
>
> 0x10205738520 - 0x1020568f280 = 692896 bytes (array 2)

Since these blocks are contiguous in memory with respect to the block size passed to `malloc()`, we can verify that there is indeed some memory chunks where we cannot allocate blocks of `576000` bytes. Between arrays 1 and 2 we have an extra `10080` bytes, and between arrays 2 and 3, `116896` bytes extra (that's more than 20% of the block size!).

What I would do is to avoid allocating memory dynamically on the heap, and instead allocate it during host-code execution. But if you really need to do it like that for some reason, I would suggest setting the heap size with some overhead margin, by testing it before what seems to be enough. I would at least expect that even existing some overhead for heap allocation, this shouldn't be too big, so maybe start allocating an extra 10% and go up from there, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the exact size may not be calculated. I will stick with allocating the arrays on the host and passing them as a kernel argument. Using dynamic heap allocations would just look nicer from a architectural point of view. (each object managing its own storage, etc).